# Windows 8 App - Sqlite synchronization with Skydrive

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, synchronization, onedrive

currently I am writing a Windows 8 App with Sqlite as a database. I want to give the user the ability to view his data in every instance of the app on any device. Usually this problem could be easily solved by using a online database like Windows Azure. But this is not an option in my case.

Is it a good idea to use Microsoft's free service "Skydrive" as a platform to synchronize database files among several devices? Does somebody know any open source projects or blogs that are dealing with this problem that could save me some time for writing the necessary code?

If it's a bad idea, which other options are there that I could use. I want to keep Sqlite as the database for my App.

I am glad to get any kind of feedback or links to resources that might help me.

Best regards

Philipp

Comment: Hello. Have you found an solution already? I am thinking of doing the same but I am not sure if I should

Answer (score 0):

imo it isn't a good idea cause the access to db files is to easy. Ofc you can say that access to database files is easy cause you need to just know the app data path to package of your app but still it`s much more difficult than just opening skydrive. And think what would happen if someone would make this directory on skydrive as public.

I would combine local db and online db. Online db as a service for synchronizing data and local db for normal work.